# selecting a span inside a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought this would be straightforward

```js
$("#info-table tbody tr").each(function(){
  $(this).find(".label").addClass("black");
});
```

```css
.black{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="info-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>THIS ONE</td>
            <td><span class='label'> hello label</span></td>
            <td>else</td>
            <td>here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>THIS ONE</td>
            <td><span class='label'> hello label</span></td>
            <td>else</td>
            <td>here</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `info-table` is a class but you use it like `id`, change `#` to `.`

Comment: Please don't link to external resources which can become broken over time when you can simply include your code here. Also, be specific in your questions. *"What am I doing wrong?"* isn't helpful if you don't tell us what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: Sorry.I will be more detailed next time

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `#info-table` selector to `.info-table`. Because `info-table` is a class not id.
See Below Code.

```js
$(".info-table tbody tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".label").addClass("black");
});
```

```css
.black{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="info-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>THIS ONE</td>
                <td><span class='label'> hello label</span></td>
                <td>else</td>
                <td>here</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>THIS ONE</td>
                <td><span class='label'> hello label</span></td>
                <td>else</td>
                <td>here</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```